# How to determine if two subgroups of $GL(n,q)$ are conjugated

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, finite-fields

I want to know if there is any known result that determine whether or not two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $GL(n,q)$ (the general linear group over the finite field with $q$ elements) are conjugated. For the case in which both $H$ and $K$ are cyclic with generators h and k respectively, this question is reduced to see if $xI−h$ and $xI−k$ have the same Smith's Normal Form, but in general this reasoning do not work because every element of $H$ could be conjugated to an element in $K$, but $H$ and $K$ could not be in the same conjugation class. Thanks for any cooperation.

Comment: yes, but without knowing that the are isomorphic necessarily, I could start by having two subgroups of $GL(n,q)$ which have the same cardinality and want to know whether they are conjugated or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that my previous question can be anwser by using the following 
result of group actions.

Lema: Let G be a finite group, H and K subgroups of G (not necessarily normal).
$$ \exists x \in G \text{ such that } xHx^{-1}=K  \; \text{ if and only if  }\; G/H\cong_{G}G/K  $$
(isomophic as G-sets with the usual action by translation)

Proof:

Let $x\in G$ such that $xHx^{-1}=K$, and $xH\in G/H$. As $Stab(xH)=xHx^{-1}=K$, and $G/H=O(xH)$ (because G/H is G-transitive), then $G/H=O(xH)\cong_{G} G/Stab(xH)=G/xHx^{-1} =G/K$.

Conversely, If $f:G/H\rightarrow G/K$ is an isomorphism of $G$-sets, there exist an element $xH\in G/H$ such that $f(xH)=K$, then $Stab(xH)= Stab(f(xH))=Stab(K)=K$, but $Stab(xH)=xHx^{-1}$, thus $K=xHx^{-1}$.